# Not possible to establish TLS with MockServer: curl: (60) Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized

Tags: docker, ssl, curl, ca, mockserver

I am trying to set up a docker network consisting of two containers:

1. MockServer running on 443
2. Client (fedora) issuing requests to MockServer

I've installed The MockServer CA X.509 taken from https://github.com/mock-server/mockserver/blob/master/mockserver-core/src/main/resources/org/mockserver/socket/CertificateAuthorityCertificate.pem
into `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/key.pem` followed by `update-ca-trust` command.
Still, when I am trying to reach MockServer with curl, I am receiving this:

```
bash-4.2# curl https://www.hostname.net/simpleFirst --verbose
* About to connect() to www.hostname.net port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 172.20.128.2...
* Connected to www.hostname.net (172.20.128.2) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* Server certificate:
*       subject: C=UK,ST=England,L=London,O=MockServer,CN=localhost
*       start date: Jul 24 14:52:38 2020 GMT
*       expire date: Jul 29 14:52:38 2021 GMT
*       common name: localhost
*       issuer: C=UK,ST=England,L=London,O=MockServer,CN=www.mockserver.com
* NSS error -8179 (SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER)
* Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Any advice or help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Double check your `.pem` file and make absolutely sure it effectively made it to `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`. I hate `update-ca-trust` on rh/centos not being verbose at all compared to `update-ca-certificates` on debian/ubuntu... Anyhow, what you have described should work (unless you picked an outdated cert or you are running an old mock-server with an outdated CA).

Comment: I've checked `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` - it is there. I'm using `mockserver-5.11.1` which seems to be the latest version.

Comment: An other thing you can do is check the cert chain that is sent back with `openssl s_client -showcerts -servername your.mock.url -connect your.mock.url:443` and verify it is sending the correct CA in the chain. If not, register it.

Comment: Checked. The chain contained two certificates: the one that was added before and another one that was not. Now when I am trying to add it either as a separate pem file or as a part of the initial pem file along with the first certificate and then run `update-ca-trust` command, it does add the first one into `ca-bundle.crt`, but not that newly discovered second certificate.

Comment: As @Zeitounator mentioned sometimes the issue is that you have something like `certificate.crt` instead of `chain.crt` on the server side. This `openssl` command shows exactly how many certs you have. If this is just one item, it is not chain then. Using `chain.crt` on server could solve an issue.